# See Events in calendar, using PHP and Javascript,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In this matter, I have a problem when site is online(live), it works very good locally but when online (live) does not show events

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
    events = new Array( 
    <? php
        $get_event = $db - > Execute("SELECT * FROM events WHERE fromdate>= date(now()) and removed='N'");
        // $get_event=$db->Execute("SELECT * FROM events WHERE fromdate>='".$_SESSION['session_start_date_s_front']."' and removed='N'");

        $ttl_event = $get_event - > RecordCount();
        $gp = 1;

        while (!$get_event - > EOF) {
            $xx = dates_range($get_event - > fields['fromdate'], $get_event - > fields['todate']);
            $ttl_dte = count($xx) - 1;

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($xx); $i++) {
                $d_e = explode('-', $xx[$i]);
                if ($gp == $ttl_event && $i == $ttl_dte) { ?> ["D", "<?php echo $d_e[1]?>", "<?php echo $d_e[2]?>", "<?php echo $d_e[0]?>", "1:00 AM", "12:59 PM", "<?php echo addslashes($get_event->fields['event'])?>", ""] <? php
                } else { ?> ["D", "<?php echo $d_e[1]?>", "<?php echo $d_e[2]?>", "<?php echo $d_e[0]?>", "1:00 AM", "12:59 PM", "<?php echo addslashes($get_event->fields['event'])?>", ""], <? php
                }
            }

            $gp++;
            $get_event - > MoveNext();
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: This question is much too broad. You need to add specifics.

Comment: What's the structure do you want for the `events` var ?

Comment: http://stannes.edu.in/                 it's my website, this code very good run and provide good result on localhost server, but not response  and get problem on online.

Comment: php code in javascript working properly in localhost but not working on serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create a Database Table 

CREATE TABLE `events` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=Active, 0=Block',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

/*
 * Function requested by Ajax
 */

```
if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])){
    switch($_POST['func']){
        case 'getCalender':
            getCalender($_POST['year'],$_POST['month']);
            break;
        case 'getEvents':
            getEvents($_POST['date']);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

/*
 * Get calendar full HTML
 */
function getCalender($year = '',$month = '')
{
    $dateYear = ($year != '')?$year:date("Y");
    $dateMonth = ($month != '')?$month:date("m");
    $date = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-01';
    $currentMonthFirstDay = date("N",strtotime($date));
    $totalDaysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$dateMonth,$dateYear);
    $totalDaysOfMonthDisplay = ($currentMonthFirstDay == 7)?($totalDaysOfMonth):($totalDaysOfMonth + $currentMonthFirstDay);
    $boxDisplay = ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay <= 35)?35:42;
?>
    <div id="calender_section">
        <h2>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>');">&lt;&lt;</a>
            <select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>
            <select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo getYearList($dateYear); ?></select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>');">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </h2>
        <div id="event_list" class="none"></div>
        <div id="calender_section_top">
            <ul>
                <li>Sun</li>
                <li>Mon</li>
                <li>Tue</li>
                <li>Wed</li>
                <li>Thu</li>
                <li>Fri</li>
                <li>Sat</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="calender_section_bot">
            <ul>
            <?php 
                $dayCount = 1; 
                for($cb=1;$cb<=$boxDisplay;$cb++){
                    if(($cb >= $currentMonthFirstDay+1 || $currentMonthFirstDay == 7) && $cb <= ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay)){
                        //Current date
                        $currentDate = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-'.$dayCount;
                        $eventNum = 0;
                        //Include db configuration file
                        include 'dbConfig.php';
                        //Get number of events based on the current date
                        $result = $db->query("SELECT title FROM events WHERE date = '".$currentDate."' AND status = 1");
                        $eventNum = $result->num_rows;
                        //Define date cell color
                        if(strtotime($currentDate) == strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="grey date_cell">';
                        }elseif($eventNum > 0){
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="light_sky date_cell">';
                        }else{
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="date_cell">';
                        }
                        //Date cell
                        echo '<span>';
                        echo $dayCount;
                        echo '</span>';

                        //Hover event popup
                        echo '<div id="date_popup_'.$currentDate.'" class="date_popup_wrap none">';
                        echo '<div class="date_window">';
                        echo '<div class="popup_event">Events ('.$eventNum.')</div>';
                        echo ($eventNum > 0)?'<a href="javascript:;" onclick="getEvents(\''.$currentDate.'\');">view events</a>':'';
                        echo '</div></div>';

                        echo '</li>';
                        $dayCount++;
            ?>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <li><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
            <?php } } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCalendar(target_div,year,month){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions.php',
                data:'func=getCalender&year='+year+'&month='+month,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#'+target_div).html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        function getEvents(date){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions.php',
                data:'func=getEvents&date='+date,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#event_list').html(html);
                    $('#event_list').slideDown('slow');
                }
            });
        }

        function addEvent(date){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions.php',
                data:'func=addEvent&date='+date,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#event_list').html(html);
                    $('#event_list').slideDown('slow');
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.date_cell').mouseenter(function(){
                date = $(this).attr('date');
                $(".date_popup_wrap").fadeOut();
                $("#date_popup_"+date).fadeIn();    
            });
            $('.date_cell').mouseleave(function(){
                $(".date_popup_wrap").fadeOut();        
            });
            $('.month_dropdown').on('change',function(){
                getCalendar('calendar_div',$('.year_dropdown').val(),$('.month_dropdown').val());
            });
            $('.year_dropdown').on('change',function(){
                getCalendar('calendar_div',$('.year_dropdown').val(),$('.month_dropdown').val());
            });
            $(document).click(function(){
                $('#event_list').slideUp('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}

/*
 * Get months options list.
 */
function getAllMonths($selected = ''){
    $options = '';
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
    {
        $value = ($i < 10)?'0'.$i:$i;
        $selectedOpt = ($value == $selected)?'selected':'';
        $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i+1, 0, 0)).'</option>';
    }
    return $options;
}

/*
 * Get years options list.
 */
function getYearList($selected = ''){
    $options = '';
    for($i=2015;$i<=2025;$i++)
    {
        $selectedOpt = ($i == $selected)?'selected':'';
        $options .= '<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    return $options;
}

/*
 * Get events by date
 */
function getEvents($date = ''){
    //Include db configuration file
    include 'dbConfig.php';
    $eventListHTML = '';
    $date = $date?$date:date("Y-m-d");
    //Get events based on the current date
    $result = $db->query("SELECT title FROM events WHERE date = '".$date."' AND status = 1");
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $eventListHTML = '<h2>Events on '.date("l, d M Y",strtotime($date)).'</h2>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<ul>';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $eventListHTML .= '<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
        }
        $eventListHTML .= '</ul>';
    }
    echo $eventListHTML;
}
?>
```

//In index.php

```
<?php
//Include the event calendar functions file
include_once('functions.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>PHP Event Calendar by CodexWorld</title>
    <!-- Include the stylesheet -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Display event calendar -->
    <div id="calendar_div">
        <?php echo getCalender(); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```